# Syntax error in query expression with wildcard

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, operators

I am getting a syntax error 3075 in the following code.  I am trying to open a recordset where the field [subject] contains the [ID] from an open form (Edit_Shipment_frm!Text105).  The subject field will be laid out like: Information Request - 1715, where 1715 is the [ID].  I know I need to use a wildcard before [ID] in the criteria.  I am struggling to find a way to do this that access will accept.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I don't see any missing operators below so it must just not like my syntax.  Thank you in advance!

```
Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Subject, Contents FROM LinkedTable WHERE Subject = *" & [Forms]![Edit_Shipment_frm]![Text105])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the asterisk like this. Correct SQL would be

```sql
... WHERE Textfield LIKE '*" & [string that contains a part of Textfield] & "*'"
```

but you have it the other way around (your ID is part of the search string).

You need to extract the ID from the form field. If `[Text105]` (please give this field a meaningful name!) always looks like "some string - ID", you can use the `Split()` function:

```
S = "SELECT Subject, Contents FROM LinkedTable WHERE Subject = " & _ 
    Split([Forms]![Edit_Shipment_frm]![Text105], " - ")(1)
Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset(S)
```

`Split()` returns a 0-based array, so `Split(..., " - ")(1)` gives the part after " - ".
But to get some error checking (e.g. if " - " can be part of the string before the ID), you should put the extracting into a separate function, where you check for NULLs, and use `UBound()` of the array.